# Mysql Limit rows by field value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on simple application using PHP and MySQL. Up to this point we needed to display items from database in HTML table. Simple pagination was implemented as well. It looks something like this:

```
 +----+---------------------+ 
 |  1 | Item 1              |
 +----+---------------------+
 |  2 | Item 2              |
 +----+---------------------+
 |  3 | Item 3              |
 +----+---------------------+
 |  4 | Item 4              |
 +----+---------------------+
            ....
 +----+---------------------+
 |  5 | Item 25             |
 +----+---------------------+
```

Not a rocket science. Now we add new functionality so we can (optionally) group items - We really create a 'lot' of identical items. We decided to add new column in database called groupID - which can be number or NULL for items not contained in any group. On web page we must display it as one element which expands when you click on it.

```
+----+---------------------+ 
|  1 | Item 1              |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | Item 2              |
+----+---------------------+
|  3 | Item 3              |
+----+---------------------+
|  4 | Group 1 (Expanded)  |
+----+---------------------+
     | Group 1 Item 1      |
     +---------------------+
     | Group 1 Item 2      |
     +---------------------+
     | Group 1 Item 3      |
+----+---------------------+
           ....
+----+---------------------+
|  25| Item 25             |
+----+---------------------+
```

As you can see Number of items on one page may vary so we must treat items in group as one item, so simple 'limit 25' not working anymore. I wonder if I can make some clever mysql query which will work this way. I rather want to avoid to create new table in database which consists groups and relation to item table, because most of the groups will have only 1 Item. I don't believe this functionality will be used a lot, but You know - client. Also this system works on production for some time so I'd rather avoid such changes. Any Idea how to make it work? Also please keep it simple as possible, because this example is simplified. Real query is already bit complicated.

I also want avoid parsing it via PHP code, because it's just dumb to query all few thousands of rows and then discard all but 25-50 elements.

Comment: Your best bet would be a union. The first would would exclude groups having count > 1, and would display the item first - the second part would be only group having count > 1 and would display a contact(group name, item name). I'm not sure how you would group this though ; probably wrap the union in a giant select and order by something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said some group ids can be null, I thought we should fix that.

When `null`, we use the item id to for the group and we use a prefix to make sure our new group_id is unique.

This is my solution using subqueries (not pretty, but seems to work):

```
SELECT 
    i1.id,
    i1.itemgroup1
FROM (
    SELECT 
        items.id,
        IF(ISNULL(items.group_id), 
           CONCAT('alone-', items.id), 
           CONCAT('group-', items.group_id)) as itemgroup1
    FROM
    items
) as i1
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        items.id,
        IF(ISNULL(items.group_id), 
        CONCAT('alone-', items.id), 
        CONCAT('group-', items.group_id)) as itemgroup2
    FROM
        items
    GROUP BY itemgroup2
    LIMIT 2
) as i2 on i2.itemgroup2 = i1.itemgroup1
```

** UPDATE **

Removed

```
 WHERE
        items.group_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: As I mention we don't have separate table for groups. We keep group id in Items table. And not every item is in group so some of them will have NULL there.

Comment: If We have table for groups and every item must be in group then I can even do something like 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE groupID in (SELECT id FROM groups Limit 25 order by create date)' and then use angular to display it correctly. Unfortunately it's not a case:(

Comment: I've tried your solution on development environment, and for some reason it list only 4 items which have group id. No items without group id are listed. No idea why.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, when testing I added the `items.group_id IS NOT NULL` just for testing, but I forgot to remove it in the final version. That's the mistake. Please try without it, I will also update the answer and remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I was playing with earlier version for a while, but I not with this one line. I will check how it works tomorrow at work. Yet again, thanks for help.